# Angular/TypeScript – turn on fullscreen automatically when orientation is landscape only for mobile devices

Tags: angular, typescript, fullscreen

I want to turn on fullscreen in the Angular component when screen.orientation.type.includes('landscape') and only for mobile devices.
I cannot use any events like clicks.

```
ngOnInit(): void {
window.addEventListener("orientationchange", function(event) {
  const orientation = screen.orientation.type

  if (orientation) {
    const elem: any = document.documentElement;
    const doc: any = document;

    elem.requestFullscreen();
    elem.mozRequestFullScreen();
    elem.msRequestFullscreen();
    elem.webkitRequestFullscreen();
  }
});
```

}

Does anyone know how can I achieve that?

Comment: please show the code

Comment: sure, I've edited the issue description.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an Angular way for accomplishing such tasks. You need to use [@hostlistner](https://angular.io/api/core/HostListener) for event listening. An exemplary implementation of **Hostlistner** is

```
 @HostListener('window:orientationchange', ['$event'])
onOrientationChange(event) {
  console.log('orientationChanged');
  
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but it's not working at all. I am getting errors like elem.mozRequestFullScreen is not a function. Do you know, how to handle that? Fullscreen is not being opened after changing screen orientation.

Comment: what is suppose to go full screen once landscape mode is on?

Comment: the whole document, I want to avoid URL bar on the landscape orientation

Comment: you will have to use OR condition as moz is not available in chrome. moz, ms and webkit are vendor prefix.